# How do you translate this code from Processing to C++?

Tags: c++, drawing

I wrote this code in Processing ([www.processing.org](http://www.processing.org/)) and was wondering how would one implement it using C++?

```
int i = 0;

void setup()
{
size(1000,1000);
}

void draw()
{
//  frameRate(120);
  PImage slice = get();
  set(0,20,slice);  

  if( i % 2 == 0 )  fill(128); else fill(0);
  i++;
  rect(0,0,width,20);
}
```

As you can see this simply scrolls down rectangles of alternating colors as fast as possible. Can the C++ implementation be as short? OpenGL?

Comment: Um, that looks like it is C++...

Comment: processing is derived of java, the IDE does a lot of work so the coder doesn't have to.

Comment: sure it does look like C++. however something like that wont compile using a C++ compiler, would it?

Comment: Looks fine to me, C++ is compatible with a lot of C code.

Comment: This isn't C either.  The above code is an entire program in Processing, not a C or C++ snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also take a look at [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) but I doubt that any C++ library will give you such a short implementation.

Comment: I'd always look at openframeworks when converting processing code to c++. It is quite similar.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for this.  Your program will be a little longer, because you'll have to do some setup and tear-down on your own (plenty of good examples, though).  You could do the same with OpenGL, but it would be quite a bit more work.  If you go that route, [NeHe Productions](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) offers practically the gold standard in OpenGL tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you are counting all of the setup/teardown code as well, if you are then definitely not, even not counting it I would still doubt it.